# Split file by pattern keeping only the pieces that contain a second pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

I found the following awk script in a previous answer for splitting large files into smaller parts based on a pattern (replacing "header-line" with a different pattern).  However, I have the need to take it even further as there could be millions of parts created but if I can filter each one again it will get what I need.

```
awk '
    /header-line/ {++part}
    {print >sprintf("part-%03d.txt", part)}
'
```

Is it possible to interrogate each "part" either before or after it is written to check if a certain pattern exists in the part and only write that part out on a match for the additional pattern.

As an example, The initial criteria would be "ID: " (the header-line above). I then want to search each "part" created for a particular method name; call it "searchForThisMethod" as the string to search for which could be at various locations in the part.

Example Input:

```
ID: 1
bb
bb
bb
bb
secondaryCheck
ID: 2
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
ID: 3
h
h
h
h
h
secondaryCheck
g
g
g
g
```

Comment: can you give an example of such a pattern?

Comment: Hi Jeff. The initial criteria would be "ID: " (the header-line above).  I then want to search each "part" created for a particular method name; call it "searchForThisMethod" as the string to seartch for which could be at various locations in the part.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You should [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/292424/edit) your question to have these details; they can get overlooked in comments.

Comment: Good idea.  I have updated the question with that info.

Comment: Are the parts delimited in any way (for example, by a blank line)?

Comment: Hi.  They aren't.  The split key is "ID: ".  So each part will start with that.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the file then run `grep -q some_method` on each piece and delete it if *false* e.g.

```
for file in part-*.txt; do
grep -q some_method "$file"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
      rm "$file"
  fi
done
```

or
use a two pass - removing from the input the "parts" that contain `some_method` then splitting the result e.g. using `sed` for the first pass and your `awk` code for the second pass:

```
sed -e '1{h;d;}' -e '/ID/!{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/some_method/!d' infile | \
awk '/ID/{++part}{print > sprintf("part-%03d.txt", part)}'
```

`sed` copies the 1st line over the `h`old buffer and `d`eletes it then appends each line that does not match `ID` to the `H`old buffer, deletes it if it's not the last line and e`x`changes buffers on lines that match `ID` deleting the pattern space if it doesn't contain `some_method`. The result is then piped to `awk`. If you're getting `too many open files` error then you'll have to `close()` the files:

```
sed -e '1{h;d;}' -e '/ID/!{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/some_method/!d' infile | \
awk '/ID/{++part}{close(fn);fn=sprintf("part-%03d.txt", part);print >> fn}'
```

or, if you're on `gnu`/anything, you could use `csplit` instead of `awk`:

```
sed '1{h;d};/ID/!{H;$!d};x;/some_method/!d' infile | \
csplit -f 'part-' -b '%03d.txt' -sz - /ID/ '{*}'
```

Comment: Thank Don.  One question please, I want the result to be that I have the parts that match o the initital ("ID: ") and then the secondary.   For the first option why would I delete if true?

Comment: Yes sir..  That is correct.   First criteria is to split the file on "ID: " and then for those parts that are extracted, match on the secondary criteria (some_method).  The end result being I have a list of "parts" that start with "ID: " and also have the "some"method" in the file.

Comment: @user7972 - no, it'll still be a two pass, as I said in my post; I've added the syntax for deleting the parts that don't contain the second pattern if you prefer splitting it first and then removing the unneeded pieces. The command assumes you're in the directory where you have the pieces.

Comment: Thank  you.  I'm going to test the sed/awk against my 10G input file.  It should generate about individual 20k "parts".  In conjunction, I am running the splits  (of "ID:" against several other 10G files).  But if the sed/awk works like I hope it is easier and less prone to errors as when running in 2 parts I first split the file itself into 10 1G parts as the filesystem was having a hard time keeping track of 2M individual files,  Kind of a mess.  But if the sed/awk works like I hope it will just run and spit out 20k little parts and I'm golden.

Comment: @user7972 - I've added two alternatives just in case you get a `too many open files` error with your huge input there...

Comment: @user7972 - `csplit` should be slightly faster than `awk` (at least in theory as it's optimized for this job) - though  keep in mind the numbering of pieces starts at `0` with `csplit`

Comment: So far, so good Don.  On the csplit I didn't see any material perf differences but will keep an eye on it.   One question please.  I would like to name the files the value after the "ID: " if possible.  Was trying to get that to work on the sed but no luck.  Can you think of a way to do that?  If not, I guess I could run a for loop after to grab the value after ID: and do a move of the file.  But if done at generation time that would be best.

Comment: @user7972 - the `sed` part doesn't split the input (only removes non-relevant sections from it) so you can't do that with `sed`; you can't do it with `csplit` either as it has to know the prefix/suffix before splitting the file so you got two options: 1) use the `awk` solution and change the command to `awk '/ID/{++part;fn=$2}{close(fn);print >> fn}'` or 2) simply run `csplit -sz -b '%03d.txt' infile /ID/ '{*}'` to split input and then `for file in xx*.txt; do grep -q some_method "$file"; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then rm "$file"; else fn=$(sed '1s/ID: //;q' "$file") && mv "$file" "$fn"; fi; done`

Comment: The last one will remove the pieces that don't contain `some_method` and rename the remaining ones to the value after `ID: ` from the first line.

Comment: @user7972 - yeah, the `-e`s are for portability (future visitors might use `sed` flavors that aren't as permissive as `gnu sed`)

Comment: Hi Don.  I have a question please.

Comment: @user7972 - fire at will...

Comment: So in the initial sed/awk I really need to split on "ID: ".  "ID" can cause some unexpected results in certain situations as it may show up where not expected, but "ID: " starting in column 1 should be a safe filter.  I was doing some testing changing to ID: and that looked odd as well.  So just wondering what the exact syntax would be to change that sed and awk to use "ID: " instead of "ID"?  Sorry for the long question

Comment: @user7972 - no problem; if the `ID:` string that you want to match is right at the beginning of the line you can simply use an anchor: `/^ID:/` let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: @user7972 - yep, same syntax on `sed`, `awk`, `csplit` - it's the same regex

Comment: Much cleaner.  Got rid of a few edge cases where it was matching incorrectly.  As large as the files are there will be some but I want to get as close as possible.

Comment: @user7972 - well, I don't know if you need to account for blanks that may precede the `ID:` if so, change the regex to `/^[[:blank:]]*ID:/` (that means match `ID:` if at the start of line and preceded by zero or more blanks)

Comment: Ok.  It looks better.  Once the "parts" get pulled out as expected I then need to extract embedded XML from each "part", parse that, and compare some values.  That seems to be working ok as well.